# How do I use regex to split only on commas not in angle brackets?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the string
`DobuleGeneric<DoubleGeneric<int,string>,string>`

I am trying to grab the 2 type arguments:
`DoubleGeneric<int,string>` and `string`

Initially I was using a split on ','. This worked, but only if the generic args are not themeselves generic.

**My Code:**

```
string fullName = "DobuleGeneric<DoubleGeneric<int,string>,string>";
Regex regex = new Regex( @"([a-zA-Z\._]+)\<(.+)\>$" );
Match m = regex.Match( fullName );
string frontName = m.Groups[1].Value;
string[] innerTypes = m.Groups[2].Value.Split( ',' );

foreach( string strInnerType in innerTypes ) {
        Console.WriteLine( strInnerType );
}
```

**Question:**
How do I do a regex split on commas that are not encapsulated in angle brackets?

Comment: I suggest using a purpose built parser for this - take a look at the [Roslyn CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=27746) - it may make things very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers are correct, using Regex is the wrong approach.

I ended up doing a linear pass, replacing items encapsulated in brackets with `~`s, and then doing a split.

```
static void Main( string[] args ) {

    string fullName = "Outer<blah<int,string>,int,blah<int,int>>";          

    Regex regex = new Regex( @"([a-zA-Z\._]+)\<(.+)\>$" );
    Match m = regex.Match( fullName );
    string frontName = m.Groups[1].Value;
    string inner = m.Groups[2].Value;

    var genArgs = ParseInnerGenericArgs( inner );

    foreach( string s in genArgs ) {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> ParseInnerGenericArgs( string inner ) {
    List<string> pieces = new List<string>();
    int angleCount = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for( int i = 0; i < inner.Length; i++ ) {
        string currChar = inner[i].ToString();
        if( currChar == ">" ) {
            angleCount--;
        }
        if( currChar == "<" ) {
            angleCount++;
        }
        if( currChar == ","  &&  angleCount > 0 ) {

            sb.Append( "~" );

        } else {
            sb.Append( currChar );
        }

    }
    foreach( string item in sb.ToString().Split( ',' ) ) {
        pieces.Add(item.Replace('~',','));
    }
    return pieces;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both commas are between angle brackets! Regex does a bad job when parsing a complex nested syntax. The question should be, how to find a comma, which is between angle brackets that are themselves not between angle brackets. I don't think that this can be done with regex.

If possible, try to work with Reflection. You might also use [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) to compile your code snippet and then use Reflection to retrieve the information you need.

Comment: Well, the first regex will split the generic arguments. Its a fairly easy task to get `DoubleGeneric<int,string>,string` as a separate string. Does this make it easier?

Comment: @James: Did you intend to post this comment to Killercam answer?

Comment: no, it was in response to your first statement that both commas were between angle brackets

Comment: The point is that we have nested structures. We want a comma which is nested once, but not twice between angle brackets. In `<...<...,...>,...>` we want to split at the second comma, but not at the first one. Not easy with Regex. Maybe if you apply it twice?

Answer (score 0):

To split the example you have given you can use the following. However, this is not generic; it could be made generic based on the other strings that you expect. Depending on the variation of the strings you have, this method could get complex; but I would suggest that the use of Roslyn here is overkill...

```
string fullName = "DobuleGeneric<DoubleGeneric<int,string>,string>"; 
Regex Reg = 
    new Regex(@"(?i)<\s*\p{L}+\s*<\s*\p{L}+\s*,\s*\p{L}+\s*>\s*,\s*\p{L}+\s*>");
Match m = Reg.Match(fullName);
string str = m.ToString().Trim(new char[] { '<', '>' });
Regex rr = new Regex(@"(?i),(?!.*>\s*)");
string[] strArr = rr.Split(str);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex I will use:

```
\<(([\w\.]+)(\<.+\>)?)\,(([\w\.]+)(\<.+\>)?)$
```

`([\w\.]+)` matches "DoubleGeneric".
`(\<.+\>)?` matches the possible generic args like DoubleGeneric`<OtherGeneric<int, ...>>`

The key point is that no matter how many nested generic args you have you will have only one ">," in the whole expression.

You can use m.Gruops[1] and m.Groups[4] to get the first and second Type.